# Why is what I set in rootScope not available in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am setting the following:

```
function appRun(
    $rootScope
    ) {
    $rootScope.abc = 99;
}
```

I am calling a directive like this:

```
<admin-retrieve-button ctrl="exam" home="home" Network="Network"></admin-retrieve-button>
```

Here's my directive:

```
app.directive('adminRetrieveButton', ['stateService', function (stateService) {
    return {
        scope: {
            ctrl: '=',
            home: '=',
            Network: '=',
            abc: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "xxxx {{ abc }}  dddd",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.stateService = stateService;
            scope.entity = attrs["entity"];
        }
    };
}]);
```

However when my HTML page comes up it shows:

```
xxxx dddd
```

Can someone tell me why the rootScope value of 99 does not show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're declaring an isolate scope on your directive, thus creating a new parent less scope. One way to fix this would be to obviously explicitly pass in `abc` in your HTML:

```
<admin-retrieve-button ctrl="exam" abc="abc" home="home" Network="Network"></admin-retrieve-button>
```

Or you could change your directive to not create a scope of its own:

`scope:false`

or just leave the scope property alone (don't declare it), however passing in a directives dependencies through a scope of its own is good practice IMO, it's more explicit and gets rid of hidden dependencies.

Comment: Speahvand - I already set abc="abc" but still it does not give the right thing. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure you're setting it correctly? Can you try logging `$scope.abc` in the controller of the view where you're declaring the directive?